# Block if without end if Error when creating a chart

Tags: excel, syntax-error, vba

I am trying to automate the creation of 4 charts in excel.  I know others have had the same "Block If without End if" issue but I couldn't seem to get this to work.

This is the updated Code for the whole Sub.  There are 3 other subs that work before this sub but there didn't seem to be issues with them.

```
Sub BuildCharts(rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range, strChartType As String)

' Variable Declarations
Dim rngAIRThisYear As Range 'Data Source of AIRthisyear
Dim rngAIRLastYear As Range 'Data Source of AIRLastYear
Dim rngSEICompare As Range 'Data Source of SEICompare
Dim rngSEIThisYear As Range 'Data Source of SEIChart

Dim strAIRThisYearName As String 'Name of the first chart object
Dim strAIRLastYearName As String 'Name of the second chart object
Dim strSEICompareName As String 'Name of the first chart object
Dim strSEIThisYearName As String 'Name of the second chart object

Dim strAIRThisYearAddr As String 'Template of AIRThisYear
Dim strAIRLastYearAddr As String 'Template of AIRLastYear
Dim strSEICompareAddr As String 'Template of SEIcompare
Dim strSEIThisYearAddr As String 'Template of SEIChart

Dim strTitleAIRThisYear As String 'Title of AIRThisYear
Dim strTitleAIRLastYear As String 'Title of AIRLastYear
Dim strTitleSEICompare As String 'Title of AIRThisYear
Dim strTitleSEIThisYear As String 'Title of AIRLastYear

Dim intLnTitle As Integer 'Length of the chart's Title
Dim intLnPeriod As Integer 'Length of the chart's time period (which is part of the title)

Dim strPercentage As String 'Percentage of Total TODO REMOVE AS UNUSED?

Dim strChartExportFile As String 'Filepath where charts will be saved: needs to end in .png

    ' Variable Initialization

     If (strChartType = "AIRThisYear") Then ' These are AIRThisYear
        Set rngAIRThisYear = Sheets("ChartData").Range("A12:D17")
        strAIRThisYearAddr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ - AIRThisYear.crtx"
        strTitleAIRThisYear = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - AIRThisYear"
        strAIRThisYearName = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - AIRThisYear"

    ElseIf (strChartType = "AIRLastYear") Then ' These are AIRLastYear
        Set rngAIRLastYear = Sheets("ChartData").Range("A3:D7")
        strAIRLastYearAddr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ - AIRLastYear.crtx"
        strTitleAIRLastYear = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - AIRLastYear"
        strAIRLastYearName = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - AIRLastYear"

    ElseIf (strChartType = "SEICompare") Then ' These are These are SEICompare
        Set rngSEICompare = Sheets("ChartData").Range("A12:D17")
        strSEICompareAddr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ - SEICompare.crtx"
        strTitleSEICompare = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - SEICompare"
        strSEICompareName = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - SEICompare"

    ElseIf (strChartType = "SEIThisYear") Then 'These are SEI This Year Charts
        Set rngSEIThisYear = Sheets("ChartData").Range("A12:D17")
        strSEIThisYearAddr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ - SEIThisYear.crtx"
        strTitleSEIThisYear = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - SEIThisYear"
        strSEIThisYearName = rngIn.Offset(0, 1) & " - SEIThisYear"

    End If

  rngIn.Offset(0, 1) = rngIn.Offset(0, 2)

   'Create AIRThisYear -----------
Sheets("ChartData").Activate
rngAIRThisYear.Select
Sheets("ChartData").Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (strAIRThisYearAddr)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngAIRThisYear
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = strAIRThisYearName

'Change Title
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = strTitleAIRThisYear
Call ChangeChartTitle(ActiveChart, intLnTitle, intLnPeriod)

'Export the chart image
strChartExportFile = strAIRThisYearName & ".png"
Call SaveChartAsImage(ActiveChart, strChartExportFile)

'Update the merge sheet with the path of the image we just exported
If (strChartType = "AIRThisYear") Then
    rngOut.Offset(0, 9) = strChartExportFile
Else
    rngOut.Offset(0, 11) = strChartExportFile
End If

'Done with the chart, so delete it...
Sheets("ChartData").ChartObjects(strAIRThisYearName).Delete

    'Create AIRLastYear 
Sheets("ChartData").Activate
rngAIRLastYear.Select
Sheets("ChartData").Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (strAIRLastYearAddr)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngAIRLastYear
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = strAIRLastYearName

'Change Title
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = strTitleAIRLastYear
Call ChangeChartTitle(ActiveChart, intLnTitle, intLnPeriod)

'Export the chart image
strChartExportFile = strAIRLastYearName & ".png"
Call SaveChartAsImage(ActiveChart, strChartExportFile)

'Update the merge sheet with the path of the image we just exported
If (strChartType = "AIRLastYear") Then
    rngOut.Offset(0, 10) = strChartExportFile
Else
    rngOut.Offset(0, 12) = strChartExportFile
End If

'Done with the chart, so delete it...
Sheets("ChartData").ChartObjects(strAIRLastYearName).Delete

'Create SEICompare 
rngSEICompare.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (strSEICompareAddr)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngSEICompare
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = strSEICompareName
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns

'Change Title
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = strTitleSEICompare
Call ChangeChartTitle(ActiveChart, intLnTitle, intLnPeriod)

'Export the chart image
strChartExportFile = strSEICompareName & ".png"
Call SaveChartAsImage(ActiveChart, strChartExportFile)

'Update the merge sheet with the path of the image we just exported
If (strChartType = "SEICompare") Then
    rngOut.Offset(0, 13) = strChartExportFile
Else
    rngOut.Offset(0, 15) = strChartExportFile
End If

'Done with the chart, so delete it...
Sheets("ChartData").ChartObjects(strSEICompareName).Delete

'Create SEIChart ------
rngSEIThisYear.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (strSEIThisYearAddr)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngSEIThisYear
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = strSEIThisYearName
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns

'Change Title
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = strTitleSEIThisYear
Call ChangeChartTitle(ActiveChart, intLnTitle, intLnPeriod)

'Export the chart image
strChartExportFile = strSEIThisYearName & ".png"
Call SaveChartAsImage(ActiveChart, strChartExportFile)

'Update the merge sheet with the path of the image we just exported
If (strChartType = "SEIThisYear") Then
    rngOut.Offset(0, 14) = strChartExportFile
Else
    rngOut.Offset(0, 16) = strChartExportFile
End If

Sheets("ChartData").ChartObjects(strSEIThisYearName).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error occur when trying to compile? Are you sure it's because of this actual prcedure?

Comment: Is there more code to this sub that you are not showing?

Comment: Macro Man, thanks for the response.  I have not tried to compile that i know of. I am fairly new to Macros and have been updating a previous users complicated macro. There is a sub before this one that moves the data from one sheet to the chart fields. Maybe i am wrong but wouldn't the various subs run in conjuncture but not effect the next sub? Again I am new to this. Thanks again!